# if there any command in Matlab Programming that can be used to do Cholesky decomposition for a positive semi-definite matrix?a

Tags: matrices

In Matlab Programming, the "chol" command can be used to simply apply this to only a positive definite matrix.When it comes to a positive semi-definite matrix，“chol” fails.I want to ask if there any command in Matlab Programming that can be used to a positive semi-definite matrix?

Comment: check [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2360-the-matrix-computation-toolbox/content/matrixcomp/cholp.m) out :-) It may be useful

Answer (score 4):

Caution: a positive semi-definite matrix is not a stable thing.  A tiny roundoff error may make it positive definite or indefinite. 
It is possible that chol will work on your positive semi-definite matrix.
For example:

```
A = [  2 2 2; 2 4 6; 2 6 10 ];
chol(A)
```

ans =

```
1.4142    1.4142    1.4142
     0    1.4142    2.8284
     0         0    0.0000
```

If it doesn't work, try making the matrix (slightly) positive definite by adding a small multiple of the identity matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But how to define "a small multiple of the identity matrix"?e.g,when A=[1 0.9 0.5;0.9 1 0.9;0.5 0.9 1].

Comment: That one is not positive semidefinite.  It has an eigenvalue of approximately $ -0.0471$

Comment: Thank you so much!I got it.